# why is Discord not accepting my captcha token?

Tags: node.js, axios, discord.js, http-post, captcha

So I was making a bot which is gonna utilize my user_id (I don't have any intentions of breaking the TOS as I'll be using it on my server only with AI integrations in the future, you can also check my personal server where I do these kind of experiments/projects). I have done everything and have a captcha solving service (2captcha). I usually get the cookies, fingerpringting and x-content-properties from my different requests and make a guild joining request with the captcha token but all it returns in the response is:

```
data:{captcha_key: [ 'captcha-required' ],
captcha_sitekey: 'a9b5fb07-92ff-493f-86fe-352a2803b3df',captcha_service: 'hcaptcha',captcha_rqdata:'EKrvUksnQGqq25nJxCIsI222EXTg0mThFz+j7SJ2+NdkWuL85+ewEaYVkRLdH/TCx3mN9ZG/Hxut6C/iA2ZXkBLP4/NdNEL7O2/M9kpqyhKyrL/na1YpHMC7jqouawssQlmRZd8Y/G14B+R288G+hcK6udR3YbnTyaR2vxPe',captcha_rqtoken:IkV2QmFhTFNSQ203T1l2R3FQY0YwUktRMElsTS8rZkxjcEhpNko0V2E4R3B4Q2FtWWFqd2t6ZGFLVFRIUFdra2ZaSUdkM3c9PXhJNE9mRGFESE9MRmUwWHIi.YlHM_A.Ho9gBr5GV7x7hlC243auvNRIxMc'}
```

I don't what Im doing wrong, so it'll be nice to get some input on this and again, Im not trying to break any TOS.

```
const tatu = async() => {
let cookie = await cookies();
let captcha_key = {}
let finger = await fingerprint(cookie)
let xcontext = await xContextProperties(cookie, finger)
try { await inviteGuild(cookie, finger, xcontext, captcha_key); } catch (e) {
    if (e.response.data.captcha_sitekey) {
        try {
            captcha_key = await registration(e.response.data.captcha_sitekey)
            captcha_key = util.format(`{"captcha_key": "%s","captcha_rqtoken": "%s"}`, captcha_key, e.response.data.captcha_rqtoken)
            console.log(captcha_key)
            inviteGuild(cookie, finger, xcontext, captcha_key)
        } catch (err) {
            captcha_key = await registration(err.response.data.captcha_sitekey)
            captcha_key = util.format(`{"captcha_key": "%s","captcha_rqtoken": "%s"}`, captcha_key, err.response.data.captcha_rqtoken)
            console.log(captcha_key)
            inviteGuild(cookie, finger, xcontext, captcha_key)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Careful, regardless of intentions, using selfbots in any way is still against the TOS. If caught, your account will get banned.